# Clear contents of cells when the cell left of it changes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a piece of code that, when a cell in column 8 changes it deletes the value of cell next to it(column 9).
Well... That is the simple version

Column 8 and 9 are both dropdown lists, the dropdown list in column 9 is dependent on column 8. In column 9, multiple answers are necesary so i found a code on the internet that made that possible, but now the value in column 9 doesn't delete automatically when i change the value in column 8.
This piece of code below works, but only when i change 1 cell(in column 8) at the time. It doesn't work when i paste multiple Cells in Column 8 or when i select a cell in column 8 and then drag it down(from the lower right corner).

I don't have a lot of experience with coding and just can't seem to find the right solution for this.
Thanks to QHarr i got a bit further.
This is my second attempt:

```
Dim ClearC9 As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 1000
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo ClearC9
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("I" & i).ClearContents
    End If
    Next i

exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True

  Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit

ClearC9:
Selection.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
```

First Attempt:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 1000
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H" & i)) Is Nothing Then
Range("I" & i).ClearContents
End If
```

This is the entire code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lUsed As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 9 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
        lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
        If lUsed > 0 Then
            If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & ", ", "")
            End If
        Else
            Target.Value = oldVal _
              & ", " & newVal
        End If
    End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 1000
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("I" & i).ClearContents
    End If
Next i

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

  Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Target.Cells.Count > 1  this means if more than one cell sets off then sub is exited.

Comment: Ah ofcourse, so if i delete that, what can i do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern to to create an *intersection range*:

1. if it is `Nothing` then do nothing
2. otherwise loop over its cells

for example:

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim rngDV As Range, TheIntersection As Range, r As Range

    '       stuff

    TheIntersection = Intersect(Target, rngDV)
    If TheIntersection Is Nothing Then
        '   do nothing
    Else
        For Each r In TheIntersection
            '   do something
        Next r
    End If
End Sub
```